# Excel document unable to save on onedrive when 2 or more VBA macros run at once

Tags: excel, vba

I have this problem that happens every so often where I have a monthly report that uses multiple VBA macros in excel, and it just will not allow me to save the file. It says this file is corrupt, try removing the corrupt parts and save again. Only the file skeleton does not change, only the data input. However, if I transport the data from the current corrupt file to a previous version, and save it fresh, there is no issue. Is there a way to prevent this happening in the future?

EDIT:
From my experience the faults happends like this , excel file is fine , can save.

But then I run a Macro and it encounters as "Application error" or "System Error" , once this has occurred :
1.) The File Cannot save ,
2.) The VBA projects disappear.

Can anyone give me more information on what formatting may be causing this issue / any way to debug this ?

Comment: Looks like the file contains some issues. I can think of things like many styles, many range names, a dirty VBA project. Have you tried cleaning up your file?

Comment: Only one VBA macro can run at once! Put Option Explicit before your subroutine or function, declare (Dim) all variables, and post the complete code from Sub... to End Sub so we can copy and paste it to test it. Also, add some sample data, and a description of what the code is supposed to do. Then we will be able to suggest how to tackle this.